# programmatically binding images to silverlight grid cell based on condition

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

how can i programmatically binding images to silverlight datagrid cell of a particular column  based on  the datasource values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an implementation of `IValueConverter` that I blog about [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).  I'll assume for the moment (your question lacks detail so I'll make some up) that you have some kind of property that exposes an enum of a finite set of states.

In your case the value converter will contain a `ResourceDictionary` of `BitmapImage` entries:-

```
        <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="StatusToIcon">
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/State1.png" x:Key="State1" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/State2.png" x:Key="State2" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/UnknownState.png" x:Key="__default__" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </local:StringToObjectConverter>
```

In the template for your cell you would use:-

```
<Image Source="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StatusToIcon}}" />
```